# ¿Es correcto rechazar una edición sugerida para luego editarla?

Tags: discusión, soporte, ediciones, ediciones-sugeridas, colas-de-revisión

Estuve realizando una edición a una [publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88557/angular-php-con-mysql-error), claramente poseía algunos errores ortográficos muy notables en ese momento, para mí no es correcto que quede así.

Después revisé mis acciones a ver si se aprobó, pero no, fue rechazado. Aporté mi grano de arena para mejorar la publicación, pero el encargado de revisar rechazó y después editó aplicando mis sugerencias, aunque eso puede ser una mera coincidencia por los claros errores de ortografía.

Según el historial de revisiones, la publicación venia ya con algunas modificaciones de otros usuarios que fueron aprobados, entonces:

¿Por qué no se aprueba una sugerencia y después editar si se encuentra más aspectos que necesitan ser mejorados?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por lo que veo la sugerencia de edición es esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/54849

En ella apenas cambiabas un par de cosas:

- *um* por *un*
- *recuperar* por *recupera*
- *codigo* por *el código*

Shaz la rechazó y editó realizando una edición más productiva en la que eliminaba saludos y agradecimientos (https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/88557/revisions - revisión 3).

Tal y como comenta toledano en [su respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2516/83), existe la opción *Rechazar y editar* por un motivo y, en mi opinión, Shaz la utilizó con corrección: tu edición no aportaba nada relevante y se dejaba cosas en el tintero.

Piensa que sugerir una edición quiere decir que estás implicando a al menos dos personas para que lo revisen. Por tanto, ten en cuenta su tiempo y hazles hacer algo significativo :)

Como dice la página de privilegios [Editar Preguntas Y Respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit):

> **No os animamos a hacer ediciones minúsculas o triviales**: intenta mejorar la publicación considerablemente cuando la edites, corrigiendo todos los problemas que encuentres.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta. Y fueron tres modificaciones las que realice a la publicación, a modo de aclarar. Tal vez no fue grande mi aporte, pero son errores ortográficos muy evidentes, ¿o no?. No considero lo que modifiqué sea trivial, no quería que la publicación quede así, tal vez debí dedicar más mi tiempo en buscar otros aspectos a mejorar, capaz ese fue mi error. Saludos cordiales!

Comment: @Blasito disculpa, no vi la modificación de _recuperar_. Nótese que las ediciones son bienvenidas, pero es importante la parte de que sean relevantes, máxime cuando aún no tienes reputación suficiente y tienen que ser revisadas por otros. ¡Gracias por tu interés! Intuyo que fue un despiste, pues veo [otras ediciones tuyas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/88434/revisions) que son significativas.

Comment: Lastimosamente estoy (estamos) encontrando muchas ediciones que aunque útiles, resultan minúsculas comparadas con los otros errores que hay en las preguntas/respuestas. Si bien las 3 correcciones eran válidas y tal vez debí utilizar "Mejorar edición", mi idea precisamente es llamar la atención (como ocurrió en este caso) de los editores para que realicen un mejor trabajo. Es algo así como que si me voy a tomar el tiempo de revisar tu edición, haz que valga la pena, con mucho gusto la apruebo y obtienes tus dos puntos, pero no la dejes a medias.

Comment: @Shaz muchas gracias por tu comentario, en este caso fue mi error en no dedicar más tiempo en encontrar otros detalles a mejorar, eran más evidentes los aspectos que faltaban corregirse de lo que yo sugerí para 
potenciar la publicación. Agradezco el interés de ustedes en responder mis inquietudes. Todo sea en bien de la comunidad. Saludos!

Comment: @Shaz como se ve, tu actuación fue muy útil para el cometido que comentas. ¡Buen trabajo!

Answer (score 4):

Si es correcto. Es una de las opciones: "Rechazar y editar".

La ayuda sobre los botones dice:

> **Rechazar y editar** para reemplazar una edición inefectiva con tus propios cambios sustanciales

Lo del por qué, pues es una pregunta personal.